# Permutation and permutation matrices

Tags: permutations, permutation-cycles, permutation-matrices

When we want to define transformations using permutations, what are the subtle differencies betwen the use of permutation matrices, and the use of permutations?

Say I want to define a way to shuffle a sequence of numbers. Shoud I define my transformation with permutation matrices, or only with the permutation notations, i.e. cycle, permutation?

Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't matter in any way, shape, or form. There's an obvious isomorphism between the two groups. Pick whichever one you prefer.

Comment: @user3482749 Thank you for your comment, but I ask the question because matrices take vectors as inputs., unlike the basic permutation notation.

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this question?

Comment: On a computer, you don't want to use cycles or permutation matrices. Both super slow. Best to store them as an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a practical matter, a permutation defined as a mapping from the set $\,1,2,\dots,n\,$ to itself is easily implemented as a vector or array and composition of permutations is an $\,O(n)\,$ operation using $\,O(n)\,$ space. The equivalent operation using permutation arrays is an $\,O(n^3)\,$ operation using $\,O(n^2)\,$ space. Other than some time and space complexity differences, the two approaches are mathematically equivalent.

Comment: Thank you Somos